# Java and AWS SQS - how to unblock receive message call when using long polling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

So I'm using long polling with AWS SQS with 20 seconds of wait time and I'm receiving the messages in a Thread. I need to stop this thread but to stop it I need unblock the receive message call and I can't find a away to do it.
I've tried the async subscriber but I get the same problem, when I cancel the task, I run into the same problem because it has to wait for the receive message call to unblock. 
I can't find anything about this specific case online. If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried interrupting the thread? What happens?

Comment: It waits 20 seconds and then it stops.

Comment: with `AmazonSQSAsync` you'll need to use `receiveMessageAsync` otherwise you get the same things as with the non `Async` implementation and with that you should only need to `.cancel()` the future it returns you. The underlying http request might still take a bit to stop but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be interruptible, but it may convert interrupts to an `SdkInterruptedException`: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/7bf0fbec42de8a7d54875510f27fb363ca2d19f5/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.java#L877

Comment: I was listing the threads and totally forgot the executor keeps threads alive and I thought it was still running.

Comment: interrupting the thread should work - can you share some sample code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry I can't, it's proprietary code. But I tried interrupting and it only stops after receive message call unblocks, so after 20 seconds depending when interrupt is called. I solved it with AmazonSQSAsync like @zapl said.

Comment: @zapl cancel is only detected when I receive the next message and what it happens is that the message gets consumed from the queue. The problem is that I have to wait for the visibility timeout, in this case 30 seconds, to receive that message again. Is there any workaround?